# How to access global mixin's methods in TypeScript Vue component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm developing a Vue app using TypeScript. I created a mixin (shown in `global.mixin.js` below), and registered it with `Vue.mixin()` (shown in `main.ts` below).

### global.mixin.js

```
import { mathHttp, engHttp } from '@/common/js/http'

export default {
  methods: {
    wechatShare(config) {
      config.imgUrl = config.imgUrl
      mathHttp.get('/wechat/config', {
        url: encodeURIComponent(window.location.href),
      }).then((data) => {
        wx.config({
          debug: false,
          appId: data.appId,
          timestamp: data.timestamp,
          nonceStr: data.noncestr,
          signature: data.signature,
          jsApiList: ['updateAppMessageShareData', 'updateTimelineShareData'],
        })
      })
      wx.ready(() => {
        wx.updateAppMessageShareData(config)
        wx.updateTimelineShareData(config)
      })
    },
  },
}
```

### main.ts

I registered the global mixin with `Vue.mixin()`:

```js
import globalMixins from './mixins/global.mixin'

Vue.mixin(globalMixins)
```

But when I try to access the mixin method from within a Vue component, I get an error:

> `property wechatShare doesn't exist on type Test.vue`

### Test.vue

```html
<script lang='ts'>
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({ components: { } })
export default class Test extends Vue {

  created() {
    this.setWeChatShare()
  }

  setWeChatShare() {
    this.wechatShare
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`vue-property-decorator` uses the same [semantics for mixins](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#using-mixins) from `vue-class-component`. Based on the example from `vue-class-component` docs, the mixin takes the same form as a component:

### src/mixin.ts:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {
  wechatShare(config) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Using the `Mixins` from `vue-property-decorator` (or `mixins` from `vue-class-component`), wrap your custom mixin, and extend it with your component:

### src/App.vue:

```
import { Component, Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator'
// OR
// import Component, { mixins } from 'vue-class-component'

import MyMixin from './mixin'

@Component
export default class App extends Mixins(MyMixin) {
  mounted() {
    this.wechatShare(/* ... */)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to use mixin globally and prevent importing in every component, this is what you can do.

## src/mixins/mixin.ts

```
    import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
    import Colors from "@/values/Colors"
    import Strings from "@/values/Strings";

    @Component
    export default class Values extends Vue {
        public test = 'Hello, hello, hello';
        public colors: {} = Colors.light;
        public strings: {} = Strings.pt
    }
```

## inside src/main.ts

```
import Values from "@/values/Values";//my Mixin
Vue.mixin(Values)
```

## inside your src/shims-tsx.d.ts

```
// add the variables,functions ... inside the vue interface and then you will good to use them anywhere. 
interface Vue {
        colors,
      strings
    }
```